# How do I save a binary buffer allocated via ctype malloc to a file in Python?

Tags: python, windows

I have the following code

```
import ctypes
pBuf = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.malloc(nBufSize)
# wrote something into the buffer
```

How do I save the content of the buffer to a file using Python 2.5?

As you may already know, this is not going to work, giving `TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not int`:

```
f = open("out.data","wb"
f.write(pBuf)
```

Comment: With `f=open()` and `f.write()`.  Did you try that?  What problems did you have?

Comment: test it yourself, pBuf is an int in Python, not a pointer to the buffer.

Comment: Why isn't pBuf declared to be a pointer to char?  The "wrote something into the buffer" is very, very important.  Please include the system call that is doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the buffer into a pointer to a byte array, and then get the value from that.  Also, if you're on a 64-bit system, you'll need to make sure to set the return type of `malloc` to a `c_void_p` (not the default `int`) so that the return value doesn't lose any bits.

You'll also need to be careful, in case there are embedded NULs in your data -- you can't just convert the pointer into a `c_char_p` and convert that into a string (which is especially true if your data isn't NUL-terminated at all).

```
malloc = ctypes.dll.msvcrt.malloc
malloc.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

pBuf = malloc(nBufSize)
...
# Convert void pointer to byte array pointer, then convert that to a string. 
# This works even if there are embedded NULs in the string.
data = ctypes.cast(pBuf, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte * nBufSize))
byteData = ''.join(map(chr, data.contents))

with open(filename, mode='wb') as f:
    f.write(byteData)
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it would better to have the buffer allocated with [`ctypes.create_string_buffer()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer) instead of `malloc()`. In this case, you have access to the data via buf.raw.

If you need access to `malloc()`ed data, you can do so with [`ctypes.string_at(address, size)`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.string_at), mybe combined with a cast to `ctypes.c_void_p` or `ctypes.c_char_p`, depending on what else you do with the memory and what is contained (`\0` terminated string or data with known length).

Comment: Good call, `string_at` is much simpler than my solution of casting to a byte array.

Comment: While this sounds like a good idea, it cannot consider it valid because of the differences related to strings in Python 2 and 3.

Comment: The [Python3 docu](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.string_at) says 'This function returns the C string starting at memory address _address_ as a bytes object.', so it should be safe...